# CM abelian surfaces (computed locally)

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, complex-multiplication

Let $K$ be a CM field such that $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$ and let $K^+\subseteq K$ be the totally real subfield of $K$. For simplicity, assume that $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is Galois and suppose that $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ has ramification degree $2$ and that there is only one prime in $K$ lying above $p$. I think both the cases that $p$ is inert and $p$ is ramified in $K^+$ can happen, but I did not compute examples. Now let $A$ be an abelian variety with CM by $K$ and $A[p^\infty]$ be the corresponding $p$-divisible group for $p$ as above. Are the two cases different? In particular, heuristically it seems to me that if $p$ were to be inert in the extension $K/K^+$, then the $p$-divisible group $A[p^\infty]$ would decompose into a product of two isomorphic $p$-divisible groups each having formal CM by $K^+_p$, and in the other case would be connected. Can this argument be done, for example, with the Serre tensor construction?

Comment: Please define exactly what you mean when you say $p$ is "non-split" in $K$.  Ordinarily I'd think "split" would mean "totally split", which is already ruled out by saying $p$ is ramified in $K$.  Do you intend "split" to mean just that it has at least two primes over it in $K$, so "non-split" means just one such prime (i.e., $K_p$ is a field)? And you don't say if $K/\mathbf{Q}$ is Galois, so $p$ might have more than one notion of "ramification index" in $K$. It is unclear whether you're referring to splitting behavior for $K^+/\mathbf{Q}$ or $K/K^+$ or $K/\mathbf{Q}$. Please be clearer.

Comment: I made the appropriate edits. Thank you!